# Logical Operator && in if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm iterating over an array and want to do the following:

```
for (
    var i = 0; 
    i < array.length && !(array[i][1] == 0 && array[i][2] == 'foo'); 
    i++) 
{
```

So basically I'm saying "if i is less than the array's length AND it's not true that array[i]1 is 0 AND array[i][2] is 'foo'" then do a bunch of stuff.

But it doesn't work. It always evaluates to false when array[i][2] is 'foo', even if array[i][1] is not equal to 0.

Strangely though if I make the for statement like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

... and then put this right at the beginning of the loop:

```
if (array[i][1] == 0 && array[i][2] == 'foo') continue;
```

... it works. So I must be messing up the syntax somehow when I'm trying to say "IF TRUE AND !(CONDITION 1 && CONDITION 2)" but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Where's my error?

Comment: Almost certainly unrelated to your problem, but you'll want to get into the habit of using `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`. `==` and `!=` do stupid things due to stupid design decisions; `===` and `!==` do things that are less dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the test `!(array[i][1] == 0 && array[i][2] == 'foo')` in the loop control expression, then when that fails, the loop **stops**. It doesn't skip that iteration and continue to the next one any more than it would if `i < array.length` were false. It just stops.

If you want it to continue to the next iteration, you need to put the test in the loop body and use `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically I'm saying "if i is less than the array's length AND it's not true that array[i]1 is 0 AND array[i][2] is 'foo'" then do a bunch of stuff.

In javascript is:

```
if((i < array.length) && !(array[i][1] == 0) && (array[i][2] == 'foo'))
```

If I used the code from your `for` loop, the `if` statement would be:

```
if(i < array.length && !(array[i][1] == 0 && array[i][2] == 'foo'))
```

Note that the placement of the parentheses after the `!`.  The full for loop with the change would be:

```
for (var i = 0; (i < array.length) && !(array[i][1] == 0) && (array[i][2] == 'foo'); i++) {
```